# Display the active selected parameters as comma separated values with in a box in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have certain build parameters followed by active choices(radio button, drop-down etc)
Once after selecting each option I want to display all the selected items as comma-separated value with a box (It's just a confirmation box having all the selected values after which I must proceed to build)

[Build parameters]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJjCz.png

[Expected]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkJXd.png

Comment: You can achieve this using the [Active Choices Reactive Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

Comment: Please help with with some documents stating the exatct context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) to active this.
Add Reactive Reference Parameter to you job, call it *Test Data*, in the **Referenced parameters** section reference your existing parameters `OperatingSystem,OSVersion,TestSuites,ProbeDeploymentType`, in the **Choice Type** choose `Formatted Html` so you can customise you display box, and in the script section just create the format you want to print and design the HTML for it.
Here is an example with a `textarea`:

```
summeryList =TestSuites.split(',').collect { suite ->
    "${OperatingSystem}, ${OSVersion}, ${suite}, ${ProbeDeploymentType}"
}
return "<textarea cols='50' readonly name='value' >${summeryList.join('\n')}</textarea>"
```

You can of course customize the html layout however you want.
Here is a screenshot of the parameter config:
[image]

and the result build page:
[image]